# Mars Rover Images AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

`

```js
function displayImages(response) {
 $('#roverImages').empty();
   for(var i =0; i < 9; i++){
    
     var li = $('<li>');
     
     var image = $('<img src=' + response.photos[i].img_src + '>').addClass( "image-popup" );
     li.append(image);
     
     $("#roverImages").append(li);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NASAPI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- JUMBOTRON -->
    <div id="header" class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- <p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_(rover)" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/rover.png" class="rover"></a></p> -->
            <!-- <p class="txtrover">MER-A Spirit Rover</p> -->
            <h1 class="txtjumbo" id="txtTitle">NASAPI</h1>
            <p class="txtjumbo">Welcome to our NASA API web app!</p>
            <p>
                <a id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">MER Rovers</a><button id="apodButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Astronomy picture Of The Day</button>
            </p>
            <p class="quote">“It’s a fixer-upper of a planet but we could make it work.” - Elon Musk, CEO of SpaceX</p>
            <p id="mp3_player">
                <audio src="assets/music/interstellar.mp3" preload="auto" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END JUMBOTRON -->
    <!-- MAIN -->
    <div class="main" id="main-layout">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="roverRow" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <h1 class="main-text">Choose a rover</h1>
                <h4 class="main-text-sol">Sol</h4>
                <div id="sol-date" class="main-text-sol-day">0</div>
                <input id="sol-selector" type="range" value=1 max=1656 min=1 />
                <p><img src="assets/images/curiosity.jpg" alt="Curiosity Rover" class="curiosityImage">
                    <button id="curiosity" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-center">Curiosity Rover</button>
                </p>
                <p><img src="assets/images/Spirit.jpg" alt="Spirit Rover" class="spiritImage">
                    <button id="spirit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-center">Spirit Rover</button>
                </p>
                <p><img src="assets/images/Opportunity.jpg" alt="Opportunity Rover" class="opportunityImage">
                    <button id="opportunity" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-center">Opportunity Rover</button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="getRoverImages" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
                <h1 class="main-text">NASA API Documentation</h1>
                 <ul id="roverImages">
                  
                 </ul>
            </div>

  <!-- END MAIN -->

  <!-- APOD SECTION -->

  <div id="apod" class="apod">
   <div class="container">
    <h1 id="apod-text" class="apod-text">Astronomy Picture Of The Day</h1>
    <p><div><input id="date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"></div><button id="buttonSubmit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button></p>
    <div id="result"></div>
   </div>
  </div>

            <script src="assets/music/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Very new to coding & trying to make a simple web app that makes an AJAX request to NASAs Mars rover API to get images from each mars rovers the Curiosity, Spirit, and Opportunity. My code seems to work with hard coding the exact sol date. My question is how can I get the app to work with the toggle I created (just used one from http://www.cssportal.com/style-input-range/) so that a user can toggle through the sol days and choose which one they want so the app will be more interactive.

```js
function roverData(name) {
 var sol = 200; //$("#sol");
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/' + name.toLowerCase() +'/photos?sol='+ sol +'&api_key=u8vY57tt0UKbMXetRwOIfrBM7CMDI2eSTurQAJ72',
  method: "GET",
 })
 .done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  displayImages(response);
 });



}

$("#curiosity").on("click", function() {
 roverData("curiosity");

});

$("#spirit").on("click", function() {
 roverData("spirit");
});

$("#opportunity").on("click", function() {
 roverData("opportunity");
});




$("#sol-selector").on('change', function() {
 $("#sol-date").text($(this).val())
})

function solDays(response) {

$("#sol-date").attr('max', res.photo_manifest.max_sol); 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, i've just added it

Answer (score 0):

You can access the vaue of the range input with `$('#sol').val()`.

```js
function roverData(name, sol) {
  console.log(name.toLowerCase(), sol);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/' + name.toLowerCase() + '/photos?sol=' + sol + '&api_key=u8vY57tt0UKbMXetRwOIfrBM7CMDI2eSTurQAJ72',
      method: "GET",
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      displayImages(response);
    });
}

$("#show").on("click", function() {
  roverData($('#rover').val(), $('#sol').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="sol" min="1" max="500" value="200">
<select id="rover">
  <option value="Curiosity">Curiosity</option>
  <option value="Spirit">Spirit</option>
  <option value="Opportunity">Opportunity</option>
</select>
<input id="show" value="Show" type="button" />
```